# Antlr4 token ambiguity for single character

Tags: java, antlr4

I have a problem with the rule `mnemonic_format`.

Instead to recognize a simple text like *A100* it gives the following error :

> mismatched input 'A100' expecting 'A'

The grammar is:

```
grammar SimpleMathGrammar;

INTEGER     : [0-9]+;
FLOAT       : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+;

ADD         : '+';
SUB         : '-';
DOT         : '.';

AND     : 'AND';

BACKSLASH   : '\\';

fragment SINGLELETTER   :   ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');


fragment LOWERCASE  :   'a'..'z';
fragment UNDERSCORE :   '_';
fragment DOLLAR     :   '$';
fragment NUMBER     :   '0'..'9';

VARIABLENAME
    :   SINGLELETTER
    |   (SINGLELETTER|UNDERSCORE) (SINGLELETTER | UNDERSCORE | DOLLAR | NUMBER)*;

HASH    : '#';

/* PARSER */

operation
        : (INTEGER | FLOAT) ADD (INTEGER | FLOAT)
        | (INTEGER | FLOAT) SUB (INTEGER | FLOAT);

operation_with_backslash    : BACKSLASH operation BACKSLASH;

mnemonic: HASH VARIABLENAME HASH;

mnemonic_format

        // Example: A100
        : 'A' INTEGER;
```

At this point, i know that the token `VARIABLENAME` should not include the character *A* (correct me if im wrong)

So what can i do for include a single character (o fixed sequence) in distinct rule? (and which is my error?)

**EDIT**: I found the origin of the problem (by remove all of the other tokens and rules) in the following token case:

```
VARIABLENAME: (SINGLELETTER|UNDERSCORE) (SINGLELETTER | UNDERSCORE | DOLLAR | NUMBER)*;
```

So how can i create a **token** or a **lexer rule** that give me the basic for **detect some generic text** (like a *Class name* or a *Variable name*) by **also create rules** where i must **accept a fixed sequence of characters?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

The trick was the "general scope" of the token `VARIABLENAME`.

In other terms, **the token is too much generic**.

In my case the sub-condition `VARIABLENAME: SINGLELETTER NUMBER*` **crash**/**collide** with the condition `mnemonic_format: 'A' INTEGER`

(Indeed i can create the string *A100* with `VARIABLENAME` or `mnemonic_format` and this create an **ambiguity**)

So i "specialize" `VARIABLENAME` for accept a prefix, for example:

```
VARIABLENAME
     : HASH (SINGLELETTER|UNDERSCORE)(SINGLELETTER|UNDERSCORE|DOLLAR|NUMBER)*
     | 'class ' (SINGLELETTER|UNDERSCORE)(SINGLELETTER|UNDERSCORE|DOLLAR|NUMBER)*
     ...
```

This should avoid an ambiguity between the token and the rule